# matplotlib bar method not returning error bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

According to matplotlib documentation, the method matplotlib.pyplot.bar() returns a

> "container with all the bars and optionally errorbars"

(https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)

I have created a bar plot with the following code:

```
x = plt.bar(spacing, medians, yerr=yerr, capsize=20, width=0.5, tick_label = x_labels, edgecolor= "black")
```

which creates the following bar chart:

[image]

However, the variable x only contains the bars, not the errorbars as the documentation says it should.

Any ideas how I can get at the error bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access them using:

```py
x.errorbar.get_children()
```

To get the line segments, you can use `get_segments()` on the `LineCollection`:

```py
x.errorbar.get_children()[0].get_segments()
```